# When setting state using useState, what's the difference between an arrow func without prevState and a prepared data

Tags: reactjs, react-state

There is a disvergence between my colleague and me
when setting state, I chose to write this way

```
const [data, setData] = useState()

setSeriesData(() => {
  const arr = []
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(foo)) {
    arr.push({ k: v })
  }
  return arr
})
```

but he think if I don't use prevState, I shouldn't use arrow func here and should write the assignment logic outside like this

```
const arr = []
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(foo)) {
  arr.push({ k: v })
}
setSeriesData(arr)
```

But we both don't know what happens when using arrow func without prevState.
Does it need more operations?
Can anybody answer this question?

Comment: To me it seems that both code snippets do exactly the same. How do you use them with `setState`?

Comment: I think they are same. But below code is better to understand for me.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with @Tasos. How do you use it with setState?

Comment: I use the useState with hooks API, not setState. Is that your question?

Comment: You are correct, my mistake for mentioning setState. So, you are using `setSeriesData` to copy/clone all state data, right? Still, I don't see how the 2 code snippets would behave differently.

Comment: yes, thanks. Then I can merge the pull request.